# SQL query self-join without CTE or temp

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, lateral-join, dynamics-gp

**Background**

I have a select statement that churns a bit.  For sheer simplicity sake, we'll say it looks like this:

```
select AllTheThings, AndThenSome 
from T1
```

The output looks like this:

| AllTheThings | AndThenSome |
| --- | --- |
| Blink | 182 |
| Eve | 6 |

I need to essentially duplicate all the rows and add a column for each 'batch' (thankfully always two) as shown below.  HOWEVER, this has to be used in Microsoft Dynamics GP Integration Manager, which can't use things like CTE or Temp Tables which would make this easy.

**Desired output**

| Batch | AllTheThings | AndThenSome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | Blink | 182 |
| First | Eve | 6 |
| Second | Blink | 182 |
| Second | Eve | 6 |

**High-churn solution**

I know I could do this, but it'll take twice as long:

```
select 
    'First' as Batch, AllTheThings, AndThenSome 
from 
    T1
union all
select 
    'Second' as Batch, AllTheThings, AndThenSome 
from 
    T1
```

**Other idea**

Is there any way to avoid the above solution? I couldn't figure out a way to do a self join on a select query without CTE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join a fixed list of values, that can be declared with `values` (no CTE nor temp tables):

```
select b.Batch, t.AllTheThings, t.AndThenSome 
from T1 t
cross join ( values ('First'), ('Second') ) b(Batch)
```

Comment: Well, you made that look all too easy!  And it works brilliantly, thank you!